# OP accepted wrong answer by mistake in featured question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, bounties, accepted-answer

[What are the advantages and disadvantages of plug-in based architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818415/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-plug-in-based-architecture/2851880#2851880)

In a comment to my answer to a featured question (i.e. with bounty), the OP says that he clicked on the wrong answer by mistake, and want's my answer to be the accepted one. Can his mistake be undone?

Comment: I hope you'll be able to get your reputation!

Comment: I made the same mistake. I was looking at the correct post but clicked the vote above it by mistake awarding the bounty to the wrong person.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302034/as3-problem-dynamically-adding-cue-points-to-flv-and-seeking-to-next-cue-point/5393367#5393367

Answer (score 7):

That isn't something even a ♦ moderator can change. It would need the dev team. I've pinged them, but I can't make any promises...

Comment: That's good to know @Marc.

Comment: You need to tell the dev team to build support for making bounty changes into diamond mods :)

Comment: How often does this happen @Earlz?

Answer (score 5):

I’ve flagged the answer for moderator attention. Maybe (!) they will be able to undo the damage.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really understand what the flag option was for.

Answer (score 2):

See the comments in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20420/countdown-app-for-devdays/21198#21198)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can unaccept the accepted answer and accept yours, just by clicking on the green tick on the accepted answer to remove the accepted answer.

**EDIT**

I have just seen that this question had a bounty on it, once this is accepted and the bounty awarded there is no way to change it I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realize it can't be changed by mere mortals, but can a moderator change the answer, if requested to do so? Is there some for of support for fixing genuine mistakes?

Comment: @mdma I don't believe moderators are able to change it, but I will let one of them confirm