# I didn't realize that accepting an answer was insufficient to award the bounty (anymore)

Tags: support, bounties

It's been a while since I opened a bounty on one of my questions, and I didn't realize that accepting an answer would not also award the bounty. After what just happened (see below) with a bounty I opened on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441352/looking-for-advice-on-a-personal-learning-project-where-should-i-go-next), I've got it figured out (head→desk).

Since the bounty was auto-awarded, [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288672/jacob-oscarson) of the answer I intended to award only received half the rep. Can a moderator give him another 50 rep?

Comment: How about 5 of us go and up vote the answer?

Comment: Good enough for me.

Comment: Since then, the software has changed again: accepting an answer during the bounty period (assuming the bounty was set by the asker) causes the bounty to be awarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, **No**

Moderators cannot take away or give reputation to any user, except through a rep recalculation. The only people with the power to do this would be the developers, and I am not aware of any cases where this had been done.

However, according to the bounty FAQ, you should be able to issue a second bounty, which you can then allocate a second time. This should allow you to resolve the problem, but you will lose some more reputation.

Comment: I remember reading another bounty question a few weeks ago that stated that the devs changed a bounty award one time, but I don't know the circumstances.  Will search, but someone will probably beat me to it (Grace Note, lookin' at you...).

Comment: I really shouldn't have to look up things that are *linked from your asked questions*, @Popular. The one you're referring to is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818415/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-plug-in-based-architecture/2851880#2851880 "More like a few *months* ago"), brought up by [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50745/op-accepted-wrong-answer-by-mistake-in-featured-question), which I grabbed from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/what-happens-when-an-accepted-answer-is-wrong-but-the-op-is-gone "*glare*").

Comment: Diago, you can issue a second bounty after one has been awarded, yes. Check out [this demonstration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users/54888#54888).

Comment: @Grace, but you did anyways for some reason.

Comment: @Popular Because I'm nice ♪

Comment: **It should be possible** to reverse/nullify the first bounty award, so it can be redone in the 100% fashion rather than 50%.

Comment: @Grace, is that why you glared?

Comment: It is possible to refund bounties *only while they are running*.