# Question closed before bounty expired

Tags: support, bounties, closed-questions

Moderator [Tim Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) closed my question ["VirtualBox upgrade trashed my virtual machine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209881/virtualbox-upgrade-trashed-my-virtual-machine) as off topic. I have no problem with this. The problem is that he closed it just one hour before my 500-point bounty expired. So I got my 500 points back, and the user who deserved the bounty never got it! Please somebody, fix this injustice if you can.

**Edited to add:** OK, I've [fixed it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220015/finding-the-column-and-applying-custom-parser/5251131#5251131).

Comment: I did not know if your question is closed before bounty expires, it would come back to you...!!

Comment: @TonyK As much as I sympathize with your plight, it was a clearly off-topic question for Stack Overflow. Just think, if you'd asked it on Super User you would have been ok. :-)  That said, I don't really know how to fix this issue, other than being really careful about where you ask questions.

Comment: @George Stocker: I did ask it on SuperUser. But I didn't have 500 bounty points to offer there, so it didn't get answered. Anyway, I'm not complaining on my own behalf, but behalf of my responder (who was as helpful as you are unhelpful).

Comment: @TonyK If by 'being helpful' you mean, 'fixing your issue', I can't fix your issue.  If 'expressing an opinion that contradicts yours' is unhelpful, then so be it.

Comment: @TonyK: Your responder participated in a travesty of topicness and deserves to be drug behind a pony for aiding and abetting your crime.

Comment: @Will: I couldn't agree more. But then I should be publicly stripped of my bounty points, no? Perhaps a big banner on the main page: THIS MEMBER WAS NAUGHTY. It could be a regular feature.

Comment: @TonyK: YES!  Brb, system message.

Comment: @Sachin: More precisely, a question cannot be closed while it has an active bounty. Tim Post must have refunded the bounty before he closed it.

Comment: @TonyK, why were you waiting until the last minute to award the bounty if you already knew who you were giving it to? Just curious.

Comment: @mmyers - Just to confirm, moderators can award bounty back to OP before closing question? So it is an option with moderator. I thought, if question gets closed, then bounty goes back to OP. Anyway, you answered that one too, saying question cannot be closed when it has active bounty.. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @mmyers: I accepted the answer after two days. The system waits for a week before awarding the bounty (in case the OP unaccepts, I suppose).

Comment: @mmyers (previous comment): So Tim Post did it *on purpose*? That is hard to understand.

Comment: @TonyK - Frankly, I dont know yet. I think yes since he is moderator and should have facility to do it. Guess @mmyers can answer it.

Comment: @TonyK: If you don't award the bounty yourself, which you didn't, the system auto-accepts the highest voted answer that was posted after the bounty began. And that person only gets half the bounty, so it sounds like Terseus would only have gotten 250 points.

Comment: @mmyers: I thought that accepting the answer was enough to award the bounty. I see that I was wrong (but I'm not the only one: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61527/i-didnt-realize-that-accepting-an-answer-was-insufficient-to-award-the-bounty-a).

Comment: That used to be how it worked, but it changed sometime last year to allow posting bounties on questions posted by someone else. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: Perhaps there has been more than enough discussion on this topic -- but surely, if I accept an answer, it should award a bounty that I offered myself?

Comment: Better late than never: I refunded your bounty because I _had to_ in order to close the question. When we see off topic questions, we close them, a bounty _can't_ influence our decision. I'm not sure how I didn't see this when you posted, sorry about that :)