# Area 51 discussion Moderators are not removing a clearly argumentative post

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

In [On the closing of Computer Algebra & Symbolic Computation](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/on-the-closing-of-computer-algebra-symbolic-computation) the poster is complaining about getting his prized proposal closed, not an uncommon occurence.

What is uncommon is the poster mentions that he was **disgusted** with the closing and begins calling out individual users, including me! :)

> I am particularly disgusted with the
>   closing of the Computer Algebra &
>   Symbolic Computation proposal.
>
> I wrote my appeal here, before it was
>   closed. I am wondering if any of those
>   who casted it out did indeed read
>   this. Namely,
>
> - WikiSpeedia hang-around
> - Mark Rogers
> - Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski
> - bigown
> - warren

As far as I know it is considered out-of-bounds for a user to start calling out other users in a confrontational manner.  If Stack Overflow users started calling out closers on Meta Stack Overflow, they would probably get the rough end of the community.

I've flagged the post recently for a third time, so some administrators must have already seen this post and choose to not close it.

I would like to know why?

I would like to know why this is acceptable on Area 51, but it doesn't seem to be acceptable on other Stack Exchange sites?

Is it acceptable to call out individual users in a discussion rant?

Comment: Area 51 leaves the impression of receiving less attention than the other sites - surely owing to the fact that it's not a "day-to-day business" site and a bit of an oddball in the system. I say the names really need to be edited out. In fact, I may be able to do it - trying it out now (Edit: ah crap, I can't, I don't have enough rep.)

Comment: I think that the offending discussion post has been around long enough that they have had amble time to respond.  Therefore I want to make an example of this post so that the right people feel the burn enough to correct their behavior in the future.

Comment: yeah. This stinks, I don't understand why it's not being edited.

Comment: Does no one even have edit level on Area 51?

Comment: Yet another site I'm not a mod on...

Answer (score 7):

Am I missing something here? He doesn't seem like he's being particularly insulting - I mean, he's not calling you names, or making comments about your mother. He does refer to the closing as a "...hasty, uninformed decision...", which I can understand might get your hackles up, but even then he explains his rationale (the lack of a response to his appeal).

As for "calling out" individual users... The names he's posted are public information - close-votes are *not* anonymous - and he seems to be simply asking for some discussion or justification for the action - which you've obligingly provided. You're under no obligation to do so (the close reason you selected *should* describe your reasoning), but I don't see any reason why he shouldn't ask for clarification if he feels the closing was in error.

Nevertheless, the list is unnecessary. While I don't feel it was particularly argumentative, I've removed it in the interest of focusing your attention. Since this has obviously been concerning to you, I recommend putting your soul at ease by either responding to his [previous discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/difference-between-computer-algebra-and-theoretical-computer-science), or expressing agreement with Adam's answer (if indeed you do agree with his assessment).

Comment: Really?  So your saying it's ok to list users in discussion rants, and talk about how much you disapprove of their behavior?  This kind of sounds like an apologist argument.  I've seen many posts on meta here that only mention one user and that name was usually removed.  How is listing user names acceptable in a post?

Comment: @Mark: ...and I can point you to other posts that list specific users that *haven't* been redacted, presumably because they concerned the *specific actions* of those users rather than consisting solely of ad hominem attacks. Perhaps I'm a bit jaded by MSO, but the post you reference was actually one of the *more polite* examples I've seen... Again, I fail to see where he "called you out" apart from asking for an explanation.

Comment: @Shog9: The calling out is obviously implicit.  If I write a sentence about how I am **disgusted** with a particular action, and then I list the names of the people who took that particular action.  How can you argue that one is not "calling out" those users?  I don't see it.

Comment: Moderators and closers are called out plenty of times to better explain their reasoning and actions. This doesn't seem too bad. Excise the disgusting bits from the post and it'd be the same as we've seen time and again. @mar

Comment: @Mark: so he's disgusted with it. Are you surprised? Obviously he was enthusiastic about the proposal, and is disappointed it was shut down. Enthusiasm is a *good thing*! If we can't support the site stand-alone, the ideal outcome is to redirect that enthusiasm to another site or proposal... He didn't call *you* disgusting, even reading between the lines this amounts to, "Some users made what I consider to be a disgusting action".

Comment: @Shog9: Simply because one is "disgusted" is not a surprise, what is a surprise is that someone would use that word in a post about other users actions.  Simply because one is **Enthusiastic** does not give them license to say whatever pops into their head.  When we talk to people on a day to day basis, we often rethink how we speak so that we can maintain a civil conversation.  I think that's a common courtesy that the poster could have followed but chose not to.

Comment: @random: Can you show me a link to where closers usernames were listed in a negative context and the post was not edited or closed?  If that post exists is that still acceptable behavior?  probably not.

Comment: Calling out the voters didn't add anything of value to the discussion. Therefore, I think it was the right thing to remove the list. The question itself (including the disgust) is surely a valid one

Comment: @Mark: others are not always as polite as we might wish them to be. Whether or not this is a *problem* depends largely on you. When we started regularly closing questions on SO in large numbers, folks called us nazis, fascists, blockwarts... At some point, public action *demands* you have a thicker skin.

Comment: @Shog9: Trust me, I have thick-skin most of the time, I've closed legions of proposals and questions on other sites.  But naming names is out-of-bounds so I'm calling a spade, a spade.  I understand that you disagree with me, but I just think you are misjudging this situation.

Comment: @Mark: I get where you're coming from, I just think you're overreacting. Regardless, the list has been removed.

Comment: @Shog9: So can you find me a link where naming closers was considered acceptable?  I'm probably taking this too far, as you say, but in doing so I ensure that some will think twice before allowing this bad behavior to stand.

Comment: @Mark: [here's a recent one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83411/question-closed-before-bounty-expired)...

Comment: @Shog9: That's post lists a specific moderator, not a list of non-moderator closers.  I agree that every site should be able to question the moderators who have unilateral power that was given to them, rather than earned through the reputation system.   **I disagree that users should be able to call out a list of regular users who close in a negative rant, and I think that it's just common decency.**

Comment: Since a moderator can close a question without the help of the community, it's necessary to be able to call them out.  But the average users can only close with the help of the community, in that sense it should not acceptable for them to be called out, for they represent the will of the community.  Instead the focus should be on the behavior rather than the users.  Listing names factionalizes a community into us vs. them groups, creating more problems down the road.

Comment: @Mark: just to clarify here, "calling a user out" for abuse or retribution is *never* appropriate - *regardless* of whether or not they're a moderator. That said, when you vote to close, that's a public action - your names are visible to *anyone* who views the question, indexed by search engines, etc... There is *some* expectation that you'll stand behind your decision, or at least put up with users questioning it. But, I have to admit I can't easily find an outstanding example on Meta where the users are *listed* - the common pattern is a simple link to the question, where the names are found

Comment: @Shog9: In my view the listing of the closers in the closed proposal/question is fair and quite enough.  If 5 people agree on anything there is probably a justifiable cause behind it.  At that point the poster needs to be addressing the community in their ant-close arguments rather than specific users.

Comment: Bottom-line is that it is never acceptable to call out a list of closers.  I don't know of any context where this could possibly be positive for the community.

Comment: @Mark: ultimately, this is what happens - regardless of who voted to close it, 5 trusted users (or one moderator) can re-open the question. But I wish to stress a point being lost here: if you vote to close a question and a plausible argument is made that the closing was unjustified, you would be wise to refute that argument. Better you make a good case for the question *staying* closed than face a scenario where 5 *other* users must close it again.

Comment: I love making arguments, for closing, for reopening, for everything, that's great, I love it. In my view almost every argument is a valid topic. What I don't love, specifically, is the calling out of a list of closers who were acting in **good faith**.  Calling out closers is unacceptable, how could it be acceptable?  **You can still argue against closing without targeting individual non-moderator users.  It's totally unnecessary, uncalled for, and inappropriate.**

Comment: @Mark: bottom-line, you're already "called out" the minute the question is closed. There *are* down-sides to this; but the up-side is accountability: you and four peers are acting as a *proxy* for the community as a whole, and must be accountable to them. Frequently on the new SE sites (and Area51...), there are only a handful of users with the necessary rep and willingness to close - the danger here is that they become disconnected from the wider community, acting without giving or accepting feedback. The public list of names acts, in a small way, to combat this.

Comment: So your saying that it is somehow in the community's benefit to call out a list of closers, rather than simply focusing on the specific behavior that is disagreed with?  I don't see it, man, that's a weak argument.  The community clearly suffers when unnecessary divisiveness is introduced.

Comment: @Mark: I hate to drag you back to it, since we so obviously disagree as to the tone, but... The A51 discussion that prompted you to post here was the second one posted on the topic by its author, and the *only* one you responded to. To me, it appeared that you not only didn't feel his arguments had merit, but didn't even consider them important enough to bother refuting. This is not a sign of a healthy community... Why should anyone bother to express their opinions, argue for their position, if the top users are going to ignore them anyway? Say what you will, but naming got your attention.

Comment: But did it not inspire divisiveness?  Sure I could get everyone's attention by yelling fire in a crowded room, but that doesn't mean that person's behavior should remain unchecked.  I don't contend to be a top user there or that the unhealthiness of the community is due to their activities, I don't know if pointing the finger at them or me is at all positive or warranted.  I think the problem is that the system is broken, such that people who don't understand the community can post proposals.

Comment: @mark: I don't think pointing fingers is helpful at all here. The guy wanted an explanation for what was done fom those who did it - and he got it (sorta). I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Shog9: How can say both "I don't think pointing fingers is helpful at all here." and "I don't see the problem".  You just stated that pointing fingers is a problem, and that's what the poster did.  Are you not snared in your own logic?

Comment: @mark: I'm typing this on a phone while grilling burgers, so forgive me for being brief ;-) - your chief complaint seems to be your name appearng in a close-dicussion... BUT YOUR NAME WAS ASSOCIATED AS SOON AS THE PROPOSAL WAS CLOSED! That's how the system works. Now, in a thriving community, any number of users would have jumped forward to answer the question, but Area51 isn't MSO - there's just not as much meta-participation. So the names of the closing users were mentioned - so what? He didn't *attack you*. If you feel a finger was pointed at you, I'm not sure what I can say, but, *don't*!

Comment: "if you feel a finger was pointed at you, I'm not sure what I can say, but, don't!" <- huh?  How can it be logical to argue both for and against finger pointing?  Isn't that what this is all about?  **I think your trying to have your cake and eat it too.**

Comment: Like this, @Mark: I don't think he "called you out". He reproduced the *list* of involved  users *from the proposal itself* - presumably hoping *one* of them would take notice. And *one* of them did... **So far, so good.** But, you took it personally. Again, no one was *singled out*, by the system or the OP. You took that on of your own volition. So you want to take responsibility *and* offense? Why?

Comment: Posting about an action the poster is disgusted with and then listing the users who took that action is somehow not "calling them out"?  That argument doesn't hold any water.  I think your trying to split semantics to get out of an untenable and illogical position.

Comment: @mark: and I'm convinced, after sixhours of utterly fruitless discussion, that you are determined to take offense where none exists. May it bring you all the joy it has to offer...

Comment: I'm sorry you are offended, I believe I presented a logical and consistent complaint about behavior I believe was inappropriate.  I know it maybe hard for you to understand this, but any user on that list of names was probably offended.  I don't think I would have gotten any support from the community if I was off-my-rocker, if you will.  I hope in the future you will think twice before defending this kind of behavior.

Comment: @Shog9 The person who originally posted the proposal wasn't even following the Area 51 FAQ. Then, he goes on a rant on the discussion board naming names. I'm disgusted that you didn't even research the rules and the original argument, instead attacking a person who is doing the moderator's job closing invalid proposals. Your decision to answer in this way is hasty and uninformed.

Comment: @jennyfofenny: Thank you for the thoughtful answer you posted in the A51 discussion. That's *just* the sort of community support that makes life easier for closers and, um, closees alike. Please note, again, that the "naming names" argument is irrelevant - there is *no* option to close anonymously. Believe me when I say I am more than familiar with the problems this can cause... But that's how it works. If you vote to close, you *will* be named, end of story. Frankly, I'm saddened that anyone with enough experience on SE to be involved in closing proposals on A51 would fail to realize this.

Comment: @Shog9 Even if there is no option to close anonymously, that shouldn't mean that a person should point fingers at people (without unilateral privileges) to shame them into accepting their invalid proposal. Users should all realize that not all proposals will be accepted and should respect the voice of the community. However, I do believe that pointing people in the direction of the FAQ to help them come up with valid proposals is good practice in general.

Comment: @Shog9 Additionally, I think by allowing this kind of behavior, we will foster a negative environment at that site - which could lead to loss of traffic, users, and activity. We do have the power to disallow this kind of derogatory behavior towards regular users and we should use it to help build a positive, welcoming community. The close vote information is openly available in connection with the question/proposal (as you have stated), so it's not censorship. However, allowing people to rant about their fellow users doesn't seem like a good precedent to be setting.

Comment: @jennyfofenny: again, it's not appropriate to harass *any* user on *any* SE site - most of the moderators are volunteers, donating their time to the a site they care about. I don't know why you would make an exception for "unilateral" closing.

Comment: And @jenny: I've admitted, in both the answer and several comments, that I may be missing something important here. If there's a past context of abuse from this user, or if I'm simply overlooking something in the text itself that you feel is important to understanding the perception of abuse shared by you and Mark, then *please*, *enlighten me!*

Comment: @Shog9 I agree that users should not harass moderators, either. However, users should have some recourse against a unilateral close. At least with a close vote, several people have agreed that something about the proposal is nonviable. I also think the question in this case would have been fine if they hadn't attacked the users(by expressing his disgust) and listed them specifically (to publicly shame them, apparently). The question is a valid question, but it should have been asked with civility. Users shouldn't be allowed to attack and shame others when really, they should just read the FAQ.

Comment: @jennyfofenny: users have *exactly* the same recourse against a moderator-closing as they do against a group of trusted users closing: address problems with the question/proposal, refute criticisms, convince trusted community and/or moderators to re-open. The *important* differences when it comes to moderator action are that it happens instantly and only one name is affixed. There is *no* expectation that users should debate moderators but STFU and quietly bow to the will of trusted users. And civility should *always* be expected, regardless of how the action being disputed came about.

Comment: @Shog9 The question about the proposal is fine. And you're right that there should always be an appeal process. However, this is an endemic issue with Area 51; users can immediately submit bogus proposals without any rep or knowledge of the site. Mods and regular users are constantly fighting to make sure that all the proposals are valid. The question would have been fine if the tone of the question wasn't accusatory, mean and intended to shame the users who voted to close. Meanwhile, this rude user didn't have the foresight or decency to read the FAQ.

Comment: Linked question is "removed from Area 51 Discussions for reasons of moderation".